# How to set a control's DataValue to a number in MS Dyanamics CRM 4.0?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I need to set the value of a field in a form via JavaScript. The source of the data is from another source, via an IFRAME.  I'm running this code in the onload of the ASPX page in the IFRAME:

```
// Get value from source
var currencyText = document.getElementById("contractValue").value;

// Convert that value to a number, stripping out non-number characters.
var currencyNumber = new Number(currencyText.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));

//  Set the value in the CRM field.
parent.crmForm.all.targetCurrencyField.DataValue = currencyNumber;
```

When I do this I get an message "This control only accepts numbers or null as input".  What is the acceptable way to load a value into a currency field in MS CRM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
//strip non numeric characters from currencyText
parent.crmForm.all.targetCurrencyField.DataValue = parseInt(currencyText)
```

Comment: That worked, though I changed it to parseFloat to make sure I captured the cents.  Any idea why this works, but new Number() doesn't?

Comment: You didn't want new Number() because that was actually creating an object. You could have done parent.crmForm.all.targetCurrencyField.DataValue = Number(currencyText) instead.